# What is the function for @ColumnTransformer to support SQLSERVER?

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm very new to Spring Boot. I'm trying to encrypt personal data in the database. I've found the **@ColumnTransformer annotation** which can be set inside the model.

For **PostgreSQL**, I've found that It can use **PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT/PGP_SYM_DECRYPT** functions. Like

```
@ColumnTransformer(
        read = "PGP_SYM_DECRYPT(email, 'secret-key-12345')",
        write = "PGP_SYM_ENCRYPT (?, 'secret-key-12345')"
)
private String email;
```

For **MySQL**, There are **AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT** can be used.

But I cannot find any encrypt/decrypt functions to support **SQLSERVER**.

Is there any way to implement **@ColumnTransformer** with **SQLSERVER** or I just need to go back to the old fashion like encrypt value before save and decrypt it after getting data from DB.

Comment: Check [`ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbypassphrase-transact-sql), [`ENCRYPTBYKEY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql), and [`ENCRYPTBYCERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbycert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). All have links at the bottom to their `DECRYPT...` counterparts.

Comment: If you're looking to encrypt something, have a look at [ENCRYPTBYKEY (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/encryptbykey-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). If it's simply hashing, then [HASHBYTES (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).